# How to use parseFloat in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have values like product_quantity, rate, amt, tax_cat,transport and so on which are string. I have to parse those values in float in node.js. I tried below code. But it is giving "Unexpected identifier" i.e. parseFloat

```
var amt= parseFloat(product_quantity) -- parseFloat(rate);
var txt_amt = (parseFloat(amt) * parseFloat(tax_cat)/100;
var net= parseFloat(amt)--parseFloat(txt_amt)--parseFloat(transport)
```

How to declare parseFloat before I use it in node.js?

Comment: What is `--`? May be you wanted to use `-`?

Comment: You are missing a `)`. Also you only have to parse strings. `amt` is not a string.

Comment: @AlexeyTen: `foo -- bar` is the same as `foo - (-bar)`. Whether that's intended... probably not.

Comment: @FelixKling nope. `> a=1;b=2; a--b
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on my node 4

Comment: @FelixKling while this works `> a=1;b=2; a- -b`

Comment: So, actually, there are two questions: what for you use `parseFloat`, and why you wrote decrement (`--`) instead of minus (`-`)

Comment: Sorry actually --  is used in angular.js for addition and i was trying to use it in node.js. Issue solved . Thank you all..

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Uh right. It's interpreted as `(foo--) bar`....